P-MOSFET always conducting
I have this cirucit I designed for my PCB.
It has a P-MOSFET (Si2347DS-T1-GE3) - https://www.vishay.com/docs/62827/si2347ds.pdf
connected to two resistors and a capacitor.

The idea is that with the signal PWR_SENS coming from the microcontroller, I should be able to make the +3V3sens = +3V3 or +3V3sens = 0 V.
This is used to power up some sensors.

What I have found is that, with PWR_SENS = 3V3, the mosfet (Q20) is conducting (?) and I can see 3V3 at the drain (so at +3V3sens).
This was not the behaviour I expected. I was expecting the transistor to not be conducting as Vgs=Vg-Vs=3.3-3.3 = 0V, and the Vgsth in the datasheet is indicated to be -1V.
I had a spare Si2319CDS mosfet, I tried soldering this one to test if the Si2347DS was broken, but I got the same result.
Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated!!
Thanks

Are you sure the MOSFET is mounted correctly? If you somehow swapped drain and source connections you'll have the body diode conducting even if the MOSFET is kept off.

@Rohat Kılıç yes, the MOSFET is mounted correctly. I have double checked

It's not the FET conducting.
If you turn off the FET, you have an unpowered sensor or potentially multiple unpowered sensors on SPI bus.
If any pin is set high from the MCU to the unpowered chips, like SCK or MOSI, and especially the SS, it will try to pull the switched 3V3 supply high to 3V3, through the pull-up and via the internal ESD protection diodes of the sensor.
You can verify this be removing the FET so it can't power the rest of the chips and measuring the switched supply.
(As a side note, even if it is a problem of the FET conducting, if you fix that issue, you are still left with the issue I said, and it must be fixed. Also you cannot have unpowered sensors on a bus if you still expect to be able to communicate with other powered chips on the same bus).

Hi @Justme. Thanks a lot for your answer.
I was having trouble with the powering up of the sensors, they were giving me weird readings, so I thought desabling the power supply would be ideal to control this power up.
I understand from your answer that I need to have ALL the chips powered on, on the same SPI line, even if I am just communicating with one of them. In fact, in this line I have 4 pressure sensors and a flash device.
In that case, the circuit I made to cut the 3V3 voltage makes no sense, and I might better keep the power always on.
Would you suggest any other changes?

@latiaesa I don't know what your circuit looks like and what problems you have with it. You could start a new question about your original problem which you tried to fix by implementing a switched supply, which was not the right solution but just made it worse. You may have errors in your code or hardware so post these details in your new question.
